# Click method in the code is skipping when executed the runner class

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I have created the base class in page package which is under src/test/java/Stepdefinations/pages. Created the Account class(page object) in page package. Created Account steps class(step defination file), Runner class in stepdefination package.

When I executed the runner class, I'm able to open the browser  but the click method is selenium base class is not happening.

```
//Selenium base class:

    package Stepdfinations.pages;


    import java.io.File;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    public class SeleniumBaseclass 
    {


        Properties prop;
        public HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        String currenturl;

        protected WebDriver driver;
        public SeleniumBaseclass (WebDriver driver)
        {
            this.driver=driver;
        }
     public void Property() throws Exception
        {




                File f= new File("C:\\Users\\watareuman9\\workspace\\Cucumberproject\\src\\test\\resources\\data\\config.property");

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                prop=new Properties();

                       prop.load(fis);
                       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", getChromespath());
                       driver=new ChromeDriver();
                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                    driver.get(getAppurl());
                    Thread.sleep(500);


        }
                       public String getChromespath()
                       {
                               return prop.getProperty("ChromePath");
                       }

                       public String getAppurl()
                       {
                               return prop.getProperty("URL");
                       }

                       //click method

                       public void click(String objstr,WebElement objname)

                       {try
                       {
                           Thread.sleep(5000);
                           objname.click();


                           System.out.println("'"+objstr+"'"+"is clickde");
                       }
                       catch(Exception e)
                       {
                           getHttpResponse();
                       }
                       }

                       public void getCurrenturl()
                       {
                           String currenturl=driver.getCurrentUrl();
                       }

                      public void  getHttpResponse()
                      {
                          try
                          {
                              getCurrenturl();

                              URL url=new URL(currenturl);
                              HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                              connection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                              connection.connect();
                              if(connection.getResponseCode()==200)
                              {
                                  System.out.println(currenturl +"-"+connection.getResponseMessage());

                              }
                              else if(connection.getResponseCode()==connection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND)
                              {
                                  System.out.println(currenturl +"-"+connection.getResponseMessage());
                              }
                          }
                              catch(Exception e)
                              {
                                  e.getMessage();
                              }
                      }
                          public void getQuitdriver()
                          {
                              driver.close();
                          }
                      }


    //Account class(page objects)

    package Stepdfinations.pages;


    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;

    public class Account extends SeleniumBaseclass
    {
        public Account(WebDriver driver)
        {
            super(driver);

            this.driver=driver;
        }

        @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//*[@id='bodyContent']/div/div[1]/a[1]/u")
         private WebElement login_button;
    public void clickLoginButton() 
    {
    click("login_button",login_button);


    }
    }


    //Accountsteps(Step defination file)

   package Stepdfinations;


import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import Stepdfinations.pages.Account;

    import Stepdfinations.pages.SeleniumBaseclass;

    public class Acoountsteps
    {
        WebDriver driver;
        Account act;
        @Given("^I navigated to the Login page$")
        public void i_navigated_to_the_Login_page() throws Throwable
        {
             act=new Account(driver);
             act.Property();
        }
        @When("^I click on the New Account link$")
        public void i_click_on_the_New_Account_link() throws Throwable 
        {
            act.clickLoginButton();


        }

    }



    //Runner class



    package Stepdfinations;

    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources/features")

    public class Runner 
    {

    }
```

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i have provided all the information . I'm just wondering what extra i need to provide

Comment: Step definition class is missing. You have copied accountpo twice. Is ur xpath correct? What is the purpose of urlconnection code?

Comment: i have addxed the step defination class and yes my xpath is fine

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can look into:

- Check your x-path (you can use FireBug for it)
- Try debug your code - Is debugger landing to you Test or not.
- Possibly you need to mention the Test Class or Test Method into your runner class (For example in testNG, if code is run through testNG runner, you need to mention the Test or class into the xml file that testNG use what to execute and what to not).